# django pipeline breaks admin when DEBUG=False

Tags: django, django-pipeline

here is the settings for css

```
PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'base': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'scss/core.scss',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/min.css',
    },
   'ie8': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'css/ie-8-overrides.css',       
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/ie8.css',
    },
}
```

Somehow it complains about:

```
ValueError: The file 'admin/css/base.css' could not be found with <pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage object at 0x10c34add0>.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it, the `STATICFILES_FINDERS` didn't have the built-in django one, so when collecting static files it wasn't copying the css and js from admin.

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'pipeline.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.CachedFileFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder', # added this and worked
)
```